# Calling two fetch Requests in Django with Javascript displays the result in the same div

Tags: javascript, django, fetch

I am really new to Javascript therefore be kind! There must be something wrong with the way I am structuring this. I have seen possible solutions, could involve async functions and I tried them but for some reason, I might not get the order straight, or simply I am missing the point.

I am using a fetch request to source some data at first from the API that I made on my local server. And that works fine. I am able to source the names of the cryptocurrencies that I have coupled with a username in JSON format.

After I have created the styling for the divs to display and inserted the data in, I call another fetch for another API this time external, to further source data and insert it in divs I have created previously, per each piece of data I sourced from my own API.

For some reason, it ends up displaying the data that I am fetching from this external API all in the same div, instead of displaying them for each.
I have tried a forEach function, I have tried (i=0;i<data.lenght;i++), I have tried to place it differently, I have tried creating global variables and using them, but nothing seems to work, and the questions I look for don't quite get the job done.

The data I am sourcing is the LOGO for the CRYPTOCURRENCY. BOTH of the LOGOS that I call get placed in the first div with id = cryptologo that is created and not in each div with id = cryptologo that corresponds to the specific logo.

I would love some help. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


fetch('/allfollowedcryptos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

  // Print result
  console.log(data);
  
  for (i in data){

  var container = document.getElementById('maincont');    

  var savedcrypto = document.createElement('div');
  savedcrypto.style.height = '200px';
  savedcrypto.style.width = '1200px';
  savedcrypto.style.marginTop = '20px';

  var nameandlogo = document.createElement('div');
  nameandlogo.style.height = '200px';
  nameandlogo.style.width = '250px';
  nameandlogo.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  nameandlogo.style.display = 'inline-block';

  var name = document.createElement('div');
  name.style.height = '60px';
  name.style.width = '250px';
  name.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
  name.style.overflow = "hidden";
  var nm = document.createElement('h1');
  nm.innerHTML = data[i].crypto;
  

  logo = document.createElement('div');
  logo.style.height = '140px';
  logo.style.width = '250px';
  logo.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
  logo.style.overflow = "hidden";
  logo.setAttribute('id','cryptologo');
  

  var cryptochart = document.createElement('div');
  cryptochart.style.height = '200px';
  cryptochart.style.width = '350px';
  cryptochart.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  cryptochart.style.display = 'inline-block';
  

  var marketdetails = document.createElement('div');
  marketdetails.style.height = '200px';
  marketdetails.style.width = '600px';
  marketdetails.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  marketdetails.style.display = 'inline-block';
  marketdetails.style.overflow = "hidden";
  
  name.appendChild(nm);
  nameandlogo.appendChild(name);
  nameandlogo.appendChild(logo);
  savedcrypto.appendChild(nameandlogo);
  savedcrypto.appendChild(cryptochart);
  savedcrypto.appendChild(marketdetails);
  container.appendChild(savedcrypto);

  

  cryptoname = data[i].crypto
  console.log(cryptoname)



     
     let url100 = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${cryptoname}`;
  
     fetch(url100)
     .then(function(resp) {
     return resp.json();
     })
     .then(function(data){

        console.log(data)
        
        imgcont = document.getElementById('cryptologo');
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.style.marginLeft = '70px';
        img.setAttribute('src', `${data.image.small}`) ;
        imgcont.appendChild(img);
     })  

     

  }

  

  });
});
```

this is an image of the output:

[image]

as you see the logos are only in one of the logo divs, when I would like them to be located to each logo div.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, for example I've used countries names and respective flag and I've used `async` and `await`.

```
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];

// ignore this block if you are fetching name from local server
async function getCountryCode() {
    const data = await fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
    const countries = await data.json();
    return countries.map((country) => country.alpha3Code);
}

async function fetchCountryDetails() {
    const countryCodes = await getCountryCode(); // if you are fetching name from local server you can do it here ignore above block
    countryCodes.forEach(async (code) => {
        const data = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${code}`);
        const countryDetails = await data.json();

        const countryContainer = document.createElement('div');
        countryContainer.style.marginBottom = '10px';

        const nameContainer = document.createElement('div');
        nameContainer.style.background = 'green';
        nameContainer.style.margin = 0;

        const imgContainer = document.createElement('div');
        imgContainer.style.background = 'blue';
        imgContainer.style.margin = 0;

        const name = document.createElement('h3');
        name.style.margin = 0;
        const img = document.createElement('img');

        name.innerText = countryDetails.name;
        nameContainer.appendChild(name);
        img.setAttribute('src', countryDetails.flag);
        imgContainer.appendChild(img);
        countryContainer.append(nameContainer, imgContainer);
        container.appendChild(countryContainer);
    });
}

fetchCountryDetails();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't seem to work. Even if I create a new div I will still need to append that element as a child to another existing element to display it. And when I do both logo sources will be displayed in that element.   In your answer too , you still imgcont.appendChild(img) so things dont really change.

Comment: @mike_thecode, sorry in last line it should be **imageContainer.appendchild(img)**

Comment: Still that div will not display if not appended to something. I would have needed it to be appended to the logo div.

Comment: @mike_thecode so you want that image to be appeded to a div with cryptologo id?

Comment: in the first part of the code, the data that I source from the first fetch,  are the name of some cryptocurrencies, and  I create some divs for each, and one of those divs that I create for each is a div that I store in a variable called "logo".  When I source the data from the second fetch request, and I try to append that data (data is simply the logo for the specific cryptocurrency ) to each of the logo divs, all the data gets stored in only one of the logo divs.

Comment: I have edited the quesiton with a picture of the output to give a better sense of the final purpose